# Why C# MPI.NET cannot Console.ReadLine from process with rank 1?

Tags: c#, mpi

I have a simple MPI C# program in which I wish to have a process with rank 1 ask the user for some input. However, this doesn't work.

I wonder why this doesn't work? It kind of makes sense that only one process should have access to the console because it is a shared resource, but is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MPI standard says little about standard I/O (this is done on purpose so to not limit the applicability of the standard to fancy architectures without I/O capabilities) and that is a point where different implementations might and sometimes do differ. As a rule of thumb, the standard output of all ranks is redirected and displayed by the launcher (if any, e.g. `mpiexec`, `mpirun`, `aprun`, etc.) but only process with rank 0 has access to the standard input. That's why many MPI programs contain code similar to:

```
if (rank == 0) {
   // Read data from standard input
}
MPI_Bcast(&data, some_size, some_type, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

The above is in C(++), but the concept applies to C# too. The rank that has access to the standard input (in that case rank 0) reads the user input, then engages in a broadcast of the data read.

This is still not fully portable. MPI does not require that rank 0 has access to I/O - it is simply how many popular MPI implementations function. Portable applications should query `MPI_COMM_WORLD` for the `MPI_IO` attribute and thus determine if the standard I/O facility could be used. Even when available, the standard input cannot be collective and connecting it to rank 0 only is what most vendors think is most appropriate (but with Open MPI for example, one could specify at run time which rank is to receive the standard input).

Given that MPI is mostly used for applications that run without console in batch mode, it is best to use files for providing input data.